# Cambiar de color con cada salto de linea

Tags: html, css

Manejo mucho texto, y cada linea la cambio de color, por ejemplo:

> ```
> Linea uno // esta es negra
>
> linea dos // esta es rosa
>
> linea tres // esta es negra
>
> linea cuatro// esta es rosa
> ```

Y así. Quizá me digan que puedo hacer esto:

```
<style>
l1{color: #111;}
l2{color: #ed1e79;}
</style>
<p class="l1">asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
<p class="l2">asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
```

O algo parecido, pero quiero que con cada salto de linea cambie a rosa, y luego cuando hago otro que cambie a negro.

Comment: Sí todos sus elementos son párrafos `<p>` , puede emplear `p:nth-child(odd)` para elementos impares y  `p:nth-child(even)` para los pares y así darles el estilo correspondiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la pseudo clase `:nth-child` combinando `odd` y `even`.

- `odd`: Representa las filas impares
- `even`: Representa las filas pares

Lo puedes combinar con un nombre de clase o con elementos HTML.

Ejemplo:

```css
.lista p:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #111;
}

.lista p:nth-child(even) {
  color: #ed1e79;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista">
  <p>asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
  <p>asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
  <p>asdasdasdsadasdas3</p>
  <p>asdasdasdsadasdas4</p>
<div>
```

- Documentación: [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

### Compatibilidad de navegadores:

- Chrome: 1.0+
- Firefox: 3.5+ (1.9.1)
- Internet Explorer: 9.0+
- Opera: 9.5+
- Safari: 3.1+

---

Si por algún motivo tuvieras problemas de compatibilidad de navegadores, puedes asignar dos nombres de clase intercalados y cambiar los colores por CSS:

```css
.lista-impar {
  color: #111;
}

.lista-par {
  color: #ed1e79;
}
```

```html
<p class="lista-impar">asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
<p class="lista-par">asdasdasdsadasdas</p>
<p class="lista-impar">asdasdasdsadasdas3</p>
<p class="lista-par">asdasdasdsadasdas4</p>
```

Comment: Pero tendria que agregar la class a cada salto de linea que no? seria lo mismo que cambiarlo de color, como lo harias con wordpress. Porque la pagina esta en wordpress y como es mucho texto tengo que estar cambiando de linea con cambiar el color de formato

Comment: @Jenio158 puedes encerrar todo el bloque dentro de un div con un nombre de clase y aplicar las reglas CSS como se indica en la respuesta. De ese modo no tendrías que poner el nombre de la clase en todos los `<p>`. He editado la respuesta, lo puedes ver en el primer ejemplo. En cuanto a tu pregunta sobre WP, desde WordPress 4.7 puedes agregar CSS personalizado desde el Escritorio de WP: `Them->Customize->Additional CSS`. [Ver este enlace](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/)

Comment: Ya casi, entre al codigo de mi tema y vi que el texto esta encerrado en un div como dijiste, pero con el nombre separator, asi que puse esto: .separator:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #111;
}

.separator:nth-child(even) {
  color: #ed1e79;
}    // Si funciona, pero cuando se da un salto de linea (porque esta en parrafos no funciona)

Comment: A. cedano me puedes ayudar con algo hablame por whatsapp +528681379699 te voy a $

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/g3lb80vmboag1sy/zxzx.PNG

Comment: @Jenio158 observa el código editado. Sólo tienes que poner esto: `.separator p:nth-child(odd) { color: #111; } .separator p:nth-child(even) { color: #ed1e79; }` o sea agregar la `p`para que alcance los elementos `<p>` dentro del div. Debe funcionar si el div estuviese así: `<div class="separator">`.

Comment: @Shareiv no, yo no trabajo por $... si te puedo ayudar lo hago, pero sin salirme del marco de SO, preguntas-respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo sulucione esque el separator estaba dentro de otro div, asi que en vez de separator es otro, ya funciono, gracias por todo:)

Comment: ok A. cedano como puedo hacer que un input cambie un color https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111364/como-hacer-un-input-con-javascript